# TERMINATION Stack is not empty at destruction. Error Swift

Tags: swift, runtime-error, swift4, xcode9, google-vision

I am using Google Mobile Vision to detect face landmarks and the distances between them. The weird thing about this error is that it is not consistent and does not show up all the time I run the same function.

Here is the error message...

```
TERMINATION
ert_Error ebs_ObjectStack::~ebs_ObjectStack():
Stack is not empty at destruction.
This can be an indiaction for a stack leak.
Please check the code where this instance was used.

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type ert_Error
(lldb)
```

Usually the first time I run the app in 24 hours everything goes smoothly and occasionally afterwards. For the most part though it appears. As I said earlier I am using Google Mobile Vision to detect and store certain values.

Here is the function that is causing the error...

```
func train2(image2: UIImage) {
    print("TRAIN2 has been called")
//  let options1 = [GMVDetectorFaceLandmarkType: GMVDetectorFaceLandmark.all.rawValue, GMVDetectorFaceClassificationType: GMVDetectorFaceClassification.all.rawValue, GMVDetectorFaceTrackingEnabled: true, GMVDetectorFaceMinSize: 0.09] as [String : Any]
    var deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
    var devicePostion = AVCaptureDevice.Position.back   //.Position(rawValue: (currentCameraPosition?.hashValue)!)
    if CameraController().currentCameraPosition == .rear {
        devicePostion = AVCaptureDevice.Position.back
    }else if CameraController().currentCameraPosition == .front {
        devicePostion = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front
    }

    var lastKnownDeviceOrientation = UIDeviceOrientation(rawValue: 0)

    var orientation = GMVUtility.imageOrientation(from: deviceOrientation, with: devicePostion, defaultDeviceOrientation: lastKnownDeviceOrientation!)
    var options3 = [GMVDetectorImageOrientation:orientation.rawValue]

  //  var sampbuff = cvPixelBufferRef(from: image2)
  //  var AImage = GMVUtility.sampleBufferTo32RGBA(sampbuff as! CMSampleBuffer)

   var happyFaces = GfaceDetector.features(in: image2, options: options3) as! [GMVFaceFeature] // THE ERROR SEEMS TO ORIGINATE FROM THIS LINE

    print("The Amount Of Happy Faces is: \(happyFaces.count)")

    for face:GMVFaceFeature in happyFaces {
       print(face.smilingProbability)
        print("Go Google")
        var YAngle = Float(face.headEulerAngleY)
        var ZAngle = Float(face.headEulerAngleZ)
        print("Y Angle \(YAngle), Z Angle \(ZAngle)")
        if YAngle > -2.0 && YAngle < 4.0 && ZAngle > -2.0 && ZAngle < 2.0 {

            var proportion = ((face.bounds.width * face.bounds.width) + (face.bounds.height * face.bounds.height))
            var ratio = sqrtf(Float(proportion))


            DBetweenEyes = (Float(distanceBetween(face.leftEyePosition, face.rightEyePosition)) * 1000) / ratio
            DBetweenLEyeAndLEar = (Float(distanceBetween(face.leftEyePosition, face.leftEarPosition)) * 1000) / ratio
            DBetweenREyeAndREar = (Float(distanceBetween(face.rightEyePosition, face.rightEarPosition)) * 1000) / ratio
            DBetweenLEarAndREar = (Float(distanceBetween(face.leftEarPosition, face.rightEarPosition)) * 1000) / ratio

            DBetweenLEyeAndNose = (Float(distanceBetween(face.leftEyePosition, face.noseBasePosition)) * 1000) / ratio
            DBetweenREyeAndNose = (Float(distanceBetween(face.rightEyePosition, face.noseBasePosition)) * 1000) / ratio
            DBetweenLEyeAndMouth = (Float(distanceBetween(face.leftEyePosition, face.bottomMouthPosition)) * 1000) / ratio

            DBetweenREyeAndMouth = (Float(distanceBetween(face.rightEyePosition, face.bottomMouthPosition)) * 1000) / ratio
            DBetweenLEarAndMouth = (Float(distanceBetween(face.leftEarPosition, face.bottomMouthPosition)) * 1000) / ratio
            DBetweenREarAndMouth = (Float(distanceBetween(face.rightEarPosition, face.bottomMouthPosition)) * 1000) / ratio


            print("Distances Established")
        }
    }



}
```

I have just discovered that the error is very rare when called when a button is pressed after the view loads. The error occurs far more frequently when called in the viewDidLoad method. Could this indicate some sort of pattern? How would I fix this error?

Any help or suggestions are helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could indicate where in that function the error is occurring.

Comment: I have found out that the error is coming from a single line of code. `var happyFaces = GfaceDetector.features(in: image2, options: options3) as! [GMVFaceFeature]` I have also updated my answer. @GreatBigBore

Comment: Ok, I recommend some `print()` calls just before that line, to show the input values to `features()`. I also recommend splitting that line into two pieces: the first to call `features()`, and the second line to do the cast. So we can narrow down which operation is failing.

Comment: I have added a `print()` call before the line to test wether the image was the problem. After testing it I know now that the image is not the problem. To test if the `options3` was the problem I put `nil` in it's place. Unfortunately though, I am getting the same results. @GreatBigBore

Comment: Can you `print` the name of the image, to see whether it's the same image every time? And try that split too, just to narrow it down a bit.

Comment: I am calling this function when the user takes a picture so it will almost never be the exact same image. I am not sure I can split the variable `happyFaces` into two because Google Mobile Vision does not have a method to do such. @GreatBigBore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167472/discussion-between-greatbigbore-and-coder).

Comment: I have this exact same crash and this is the only result I could match to it on google. Is there any update on this and how to fix it?

Comment: Try cleaning your project and then building again. I cannot remember exactly how I solved this problem. @AleRavasio